# I was looking a solution for a organization with contacts and volunters with actuation diarly and needs register it. Some extension required?

Tags: civivolunteer

I need a solution with the information between a volunter and a contact with diary operatons.
I think with a calendar that I can register these actuations. Is there any extensions I can try?

Thanks

Andreu

Comment: i think you need to flesh out your requirements more thoroughly with some examples

Comment: Hello, my english is very bad. Sorry. I try to explain the situation:

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to guess what you are trying to do. But to record information between a Volunteer and a Contact I would suggest you consider

- using Activities as this means the 'interaction' is recorded on both the Volunteers record and the Contacts record
- using Cases if the workflow is complex

When you talk about a 'calendar' sometimes people just mean a date-based log and sometimes they mean an actual monthly calendar of Activities.

I have done both using Drupal Views so will depend on what CMS you are using

Comment: Thanks for your opinon, I use Wordpress.